# How Do you get a pfquery row count

Tags: uitableview, ios7, parse-platform

How do you get a `PFQuery` row count from parse.com,

```
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@" count number %d", number);
}];
```

The above statement crashes the app and the below statement gives me a warning "A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread."

```
_parseCount = [query countObjects];
```

Comment: The first statement is the right way, what error does it return?

Comment: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread."

Comment: That's for `countObjects`, what about when the app crashes when you do `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`, what error is in the logs?

Comment: i got it to work, i had to write a separate pfquery for the count